# Can't get Java and C# to communicate through sockets

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I've been trying to create a **Java** and **C#** app that would communicate together. In this case the user sends a `String` from the **C#** side, it should display on the **Java** console and echo back. Unfortunately, I have only been able to establish the connection, without being able to send or receive anything.

Java code snippet:

```
public CommunicationThreadHandler(Socket socket, CarList carList) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.carList = carList;
    try {
        this.in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.writer = new Writer(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when reading or receiving data!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.ip = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String msgJson = in.readUTF();
            String msg = gson.fromJson(msgJson,String.class);
            System.out.println("Message from C# client: "+msg);
            String reply = "Server echo: "+msg;
            String replyJson = gson.toJson(reply);
            out.writeUTF(replyJson);
            if (msg.equals(Package.EXIT))
                break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

C# snippet:

```
public static void StartClient()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try
    {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
        // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.  
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
        Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
        try
        { 
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter message to server: ");

                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"To be sent: {message}");

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.  
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Send the data through the socket.  
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

                string msgFromServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                if (msgFromServer.Equals("EXIT"))
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine($"Server says: {msgFromServer}");
            }
            // Release the socket.

            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

        }
```

Comment: So what's your error?

Comment: You showed 2 try but no catch,. so I have to asume faulty exception handling is the cause of your lack of debugging information. Here are two articles on the mater that I link a lot: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET Unless you give us more information about what is happening/not happening, we can not help you.

Comment: It is even possible this is a networking issue. One downside with Java is that you can only block/unblock the whole java runtime for Network communication. As "Java Programms" are interprted similar to a batch file, you can not lock/unlock them seperately. .NET does not have this problem. It is one of the things they really improoved upon when they copied JavaBytecode with MSIL.

Comment: Java: Don't use DataOutputStream/DataInputStream to communicate with a C# client. Use something like that: `new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`. You need an explicit OutputStreamWriter with an encoding to get a Writer. You cannot simply pass an OutputStream to the Writer's constructor.

Comment: @Christopher Actually you can, if you use the Java security manager properly, but I fail to see how that is even relevant in the context of this question.

Comment: I think the message is getting transmitted but the server is not responding.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the messages to determine if your client is sending or the server is not responding.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: If he blocked the Java Runtime from using the network in the Windows Firewall, he can try **forever** to get it working. And it is not a unusual setting to make. Also "you can get around it not playing with existing security features, by using it's own security features" is not a show there is no issue. Indeed it confirms the issue.

Comment: @Christopher It was not clear to me that that was what you meant, but in any case, that is likely not the problem here. The problem is a mismatch between `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` in Java vs raw stream usage in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` in Java, which use a Java-specific, XDR-like datatype serialization protocol. You are not using that protocol at your C# side.

Switching to using the raw input/output stream should be sufficient (although very brittle). However, notice that as you are sending raw bytes from C#, it will be impossible to tell for the recipient when the message is complete. It would be better to send the number of bytes of the message, followed by the actual message (this is what `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` does, but it comes with additional considerations that you would need to correctly implement in your C# side, for example `readUTF`/`writeUTF` use a 'modified UTF-8' format instead of normal UTF-8).

The problem right now, is that you send raw bytes from C#, the `readUTF()` method reads the first two bytes as length, and then tries to read a message of that length. For example if C# sends "Hello" (encoded as 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f), then the Java side will read 0x48, 0x65 ("He") as "message length is 18533" and then tries to read 18533 bytes, while the actual remaining bytes are only 3 (the "llo"). This causes the input to block waiting for the remaining 18530 bytes, which never arrive.